# cURL POST request returns NULL in PHP but in pure cURL code it returns data

Tags: php, curl, https, php-curl

Running this code in cURL gives me JSON data :

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '{"fund_id":"74","product_id":"22","from_date":"2017-01-01","to_date":"2022-01-12"}' https://api.hdfclife.com/api/funds/get-fund-nav
```

But when using curl in php I receive NULL as data :

```
$url = "https://api.hdfclife.com/api/funds/get-fund-nav";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
   "Content-Type: application/json",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = '{"fund_id":"74","product_id":"22","from_date":"2017-01-01","to_date":"2022-01-12"}';

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);

?>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Also I am new to PHP so please go easy on me.

Comment: Your cURL command also returns nothing. It's not about php.

Comment: https://reqbin.com/curl

try running it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the URL that you're calling is moved permanently and it redirects the request in itself and returns status code "301 Moved Permanently".
CURL in php doesn't support the redirects by default and options must be declared for CURL in order to support it.
Just add the following code to your CURL options and it should work just fine.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this helped. Can you please elaborate on how you debugged the problem, just for my knowledge

Comment: @CalvinCrasto I used postman to send a request and it showed me that the URL that you're calling is returning "301 Moved Permanently" status code. And I figured that the CURL function should follow the request when it's redirecting (Hence the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION option). After setting this option it showed that after redirect, the request is being treated as a GET request and the POST parameters are not sent after redirecting (Hence the CURLOPT_POSTREDIR option). Hope this helps ;)